# Magento 2 ERROR: Request does not match any route

Tags: apache, checkout, magento2

**Magento 2** error:

> Request does not match any route.

while applying discount code. Discount Code OR Coupon Code successfully created in Magento cart price rule.

[image]

I have installed Magento 2.1.7 on Linux Ubuntu Virtual Machine (Bitnami LAMP Installed) hosted by Microsoft Azure.

Comment: The error says it all. The request made is not being handled by your backend api

Comment: I solved it myself. It's because of invalid Discount Code or Coupon Code name. My Discount Code has special character (/) in it. I replace Eid50/50 with Eid5050 and it worked.

Comment: Then then this is a possible security risk. You should treat it as a stripped string, as the users can send in anything.

Comment: Magento Core Back-end developers needs to update this issue. I just created a discount token with a special character "/" in admin panel as an admin user. So we as a user has nothing to do with core.